# unable to insert a device driver on SPI0 or SPI1 bus on Beagkebone Black

Tags: linux-device-driver, spi, beagleboneblack

I am trying to insert a device driver which drives an OLED module for Beaglebone Black. I have deactivated the audio and video overlays, enabled Pins for both SPI0/1 ports for SPI as specified here:
https://arcanesciencelab.wordpress.com/2020/01/14/the-correct-way-to-enable-spi-ports-on-the-beaglebone-black/
I am also able to do a loopback test successfully, connecting MISO and MOSI as per Derek Molly's book, for both SPI0 and SPI1 busses. However, when I try to insert the driver using insmod, I get the following error message in dmesg, for both the SPI lines:

```
[ 1887.341807] omap2_mcspi 48030000.spi: chipselect 0 already in use
[ 1887.352695] FAILED to create slave.
```

`ls -al | grep spi` shows:

```
crw-rw----  1 root   spi     153,   0 Jun 21 10:17 spidev0.0
crw-rw----  1 root   spi     153,   1 Jun 21 10:17 spidev0.1
crw-rw----  1 root   spi     153,   2 Jun 21 10:17 spidev1.0
crw-rw----  1 root   spi     153,   3 Jun 21 10:17 spidev1.1
```

Can you help if you have faced this issue earlier ?
Many thanks

I am trying to make an SPI device driver for an OLED module

Comment: Chipselect 0 is already in use by `/dev/spidev0.0`.

Comment: OK Ian, but I am trying the same with SPI1 and the same zero. I tried with CS=1 also, does not work

Comment: They are all in use by the spidev devices. I don't use a BB, but I understand that you can control which devices get instantiated by modifying the /boot/uEnv.txt file to load different device tree overlays.

Comment: but the two SPI busses are running fine because loopback is working fine Ian. This means the SPI pins are OK. I dont know more details about config within the device overlay files though.... thanks for taking an interest....

Comment: Sure, the SPI bus is working. I assume you used one of the /dev/spidev* devices to perform the loop-back test. Those spidev devices are SPI client (software) devices driven by the spidev Linux device driver and tied to particular CS lines in the device tree. But now one of those spidev devices is in your way. It needs to be removed or disabled so that its CS line can be used by a different SPI client device driven by a different Linux device driver.

Comment: Yes that is true... Because we won't have the character device files in /dev unless we have a driver for it. Ok let me try to remove the Linux spi drivers and try... Thanks again...

Comment: Some of the BB device tree overlays that use SPI buses proactively disable the spidev device tree nodes (for example [PB-SPI0-OLEDB-CLICK](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/beagleboard/bb.org-overlays/master/src/arm/PB-SPI0-OLEDB-CLICK.dts) disables the `channel@0` and `channel@1` nodes for `&spi0`), and some of them just assume the CS line is available (for example [BB-LCD-ADAFRUIT-18-SPI0-00A0](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/beagleboard/bb.org-overlays/master/src/arm/BB-LCD-ADAFRUIT-18-SPI0-00A0.dts)).

Comment: thanks Ian for the pointers in the right direction. it was an issue of freeing SPI.0 from the clutches of the Linux spidev driver. Was able to insert the driver into Linux, but there appears to be issues in dtbo I am trying to use. Need to understand the language. was able to make it work on the RPi though....